# conda package corrupted after exitting in the middle of conda update

Tags: python, anaconda

Anaconda 2.1 on Windows.

I was doing `conda update numexpr` and it started to update `conda, numpy, scipy` and other packages. During the unlinking stage of `scipy`, the status bar hangs there for more than a few minutes. So I closed the command window at that moment.

Now the system does not recognise `conda` as a command. I can start Python, but `import numpy` gives `no module named numpy` error.

What to continue here?